# Display link to nodes who reference a user in a custom usertype view

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views, cck

In my website, I have a node type called "Project".

Node type "Project" has a field called Project Author, which is a user reference.

Now, when I hit "reverse link" in the field settings, a link to all "Project" type pages that refer that particular user appears in the default "view" user page (ex: domain.org/user/123/view) under "Related content"

This is the effect I want. The problem is that I'm using a custom made view as default landing user page.

So, my question is, how can I add the "Related content" block to a custom usertype View (in Views2), so that I can show a link to all project pages that refer that particular user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer using another module: Panels3! Here's how...

VIEWS2 MODULE:

1. I created a view of user type, using UserID ans argument.
2. I filled the fields with the stuff i needed.
3. Then I created another view but node type this time.
4. In the arguments I used the field "Project Author", a user reference field type.
5. I populated the fields with node title.

PANELS3 MODULE:

1. Created a User profile template panel.
2. I added the two views together

Voilá!

Hope this helps someone with the same problem as I.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [a patch for CCK  (6.x)](http://drupal.org/node/375337#comment-1341020) which can achieve this in a single view.